# Remove html element with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

---

When I press the Submit button if any error is generated then code create a span element.

My question is how I can clear the old error from the error container element, or if not possible then please sum up the errors.

```js
$.each(err.responseJSON.errors, function (i, error) {
    var el = $(document).find('[name="'+i+'"]');
    el.after($('<span style="color: red;">'+error[0]+'</span>'));
    
});
```

I tried `remove()` but I cannot do it.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

you can remove the span with **next()**.
**next()** finds the next sibling to the input field you are referring to.
it will give you the span:

```
el.next().remove();
```

you can use a class on the span f.e. class="validation-span"

```
el.next(".validation-span").remove();
```

this will make sure you only remove the span and no other element if existent :)

Comment: great this works! I mean  el.next().remove();
                        el.after($('<span style="color: red;">'+error[0]+'</span>'));

Answer (score 1):

Add an span element after the input and set its HTML each time instead of using `.after`.

```
<input name="yourName">
<span class="errors"></span>
<script>
$(document).find('[name="'+i+'"] + .errors')
   .html('<span style="color: red;">'+error[0]+'</span>');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I updated the both way you want, please pick which is more suitable to you

```js
function logErrorCleanSpan(errorMessage){
  $('#errorContainer').text(errorMessage);
}
logErrorCleanSpan("Hello");
logErrorCleanSpan("Jarvis");



function logErrorAppendSpan(errorMessage){
  var span  = $("<span>"+errorMessage+"</span>");
  $('#errorContainerSpanAppend').append(span);
}
logErrorAppendSpan("1. Hello ");
logErrorAppendSpan("2. Jarvis ");
```

```css
#errorContainerSpanAppend{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h3>Append Error and clean the previous error<h3>
<span id="errorContainer"></span>


<h3>Append Error and keep the older one<h3>
<span id="errorContainerSpanAppend"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Assign a id with index to span after each click remove previous span using id
2. Use jquery remove

$.each(err.responseJSON.errors, function (i, error) {

```
    var el = $(document).find('[name="'+i+'"]');

    el.after($('<span id="error'+i+'" style="color: red;">'+error[0]+'</span>'));

    if($(document).find('span#error+i - 1+')) {

          $( "span#error+i - 1+" ).remove();

     }
});
```

this is just an example code not correct code.